# Django admin fields editable only if checkbox is true

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hi given below is my Django model. Please help me with a code which makes circle field non editable if checkbox is false and editable if checkbox is true.
Any help would be appericiated.

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    field_disabe_checkbox=models.BooleanField(default=1)
    circle = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can overwrite the get_readonly_fields in admin:

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request,Parameters): #add parameters accordingly
        #here add your circle field to readonly_fields if field_disabe_checkbox is false
        return self.readonly_fields
```

Comment: how i will check "field_disabe_checkbox" value inside get_readonly_fields function